# Ideal of polynomials becoming prime after extension of the base field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, extension-field, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $L/K$ be an extension of fields, consider the commutative rings $A = K[X_1, \ldots, X_m]$ and $B = L[X_1, \ldots, X_m]$ for some natural number $m$.

If $I$ is a prime ideal of $A$, then certainly $IB$ (smallest ideal of $B$ containing $I$) need not be prime, even if $m = 1$: an irreducible univariate polynomial can become reducible over a finite field extension.

But can the converse happen? Could $I$ be an ideal of $A$ which is not prime such that $IB$ is prime? Similarly, can $IB$ be maximal if $I$ is not maximal?

Comment: Can you calculate $IB\cap A$?

Comment: Certainly if one would have $IB \cap A = I$ then it would follow that $I$ is prime if $IB$ is prime. But I do not know whether this equality holds.

Comment: Have you tried? One way is to show that $B/A$ is a free $A$-module and use `flatness'.